# mysql.user table on mySQL

Tags: mysql, macos, root, account

I use mySQL on Mac OS.
I login mySQL by the command

> mysql - u root

then run the command below

> select User from mysql.user;

It show the table below

```
+---------+
| User    |
+---------+
| root    |
| root    |
|         |
| root    |
|         |
| gerrit2 |
| root    |
+---------+
7 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

I don't understand that there're 4 rows has root and 2 rows has no name.
Please explain me.
Thank you!

Comment: You'll get a clearer picture of what's in there if you do `SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.user`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The row-defining part in mysql.users is the (host,user) tuple - this means:

- You can have permissions without a username, depending on which host you connect from
- You can have different permissions with the same username, again depending on the host

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple records for the same user in the mysql.user table, since you can have different passwords and/or permissions depending on the host the user connects from. If you run select * you will see the differences.